# Custom color for log.info statement in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, themes

I'm logging a lot of events in my Java code and find the color of log statements annoying.

I'd love to have all my logs statement to be in light grey to enhance the readability of my code. Anyone knows how to do that?

Thanks a million in advance

Comment: Font color in the Console _view_? **_Window > Preferences: Run/Debug > Console_**

Comment: LogViewer plug-in with more (coloring) features: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/logviewer